# Align input to the right (CSS)

Tags: html, css

[image: Red space is what I wish to remove]

So I have a website, where it basically goes like this:
Username: [           ]   |
Password: [           ]   |
The problem is I want them to align to the right vertical bars.
Here's code:

```html
<form i  d="cred">
  <h3 class="credin">Username:</h3>
  <input class="credin" type="text" name="username" value=""> <br>
  <h3 class="credin">Password:</h3>
  <input class="credin" type="password" name="password" value=""> <br>
  <a><p id="logout">(Sign up)</p></a>
  <input id="login" type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

And Css

```css
.credin {
    font-size:21px;
    margin:0px;
    display:inline;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
}
#login {
    font-size:24px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    width:30%;
}
#logout {
    margin:0px;
    font-size:19px;
}
input.credin{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:auto;
```

Here's a bigger picture.
    [image: Website]

```css
.credin {
    font-size:21px;
    margin:0px;
    display:inline;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
}
#login {
    font-size:24px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    width:30%;
}
#logout {
    margin:0px;
    font-size:19px;
}
input.credin{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:auto;
    }
```

```html
<form i  d="cred">
  <h3 class="credin">Username:</h3>
  <input class="credin" type="text" name="username" value=""> <br>
  <h3 class="credin">Password:</h3>
  <input class="credin" type="password" name="password" value=""> <br>
  <a><p id="logout">(Sign up)</p></a>
  <input id="login" type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use tabular format which will be perfect in this situation.

Comment: You can use bootstrap css instead of you own check out this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/)

Answer (score 0):

I would make it like this.

```
<form id="cred">
  <div>
        <label class="label">Username:</label>
        <input class="credin right" type="text" name="username" value="">
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;">
        <label class="label">Password:</label>
        <input class="credin right" type="password" name="password" value="" > <br>
  </div>
  <div>
        <a><p id="logout">(Sign up)</p></a>
        <input id="login" type="submit" value="Log in">
  </div>
    </form>
```

And CSS would go like this:

```
#cred {
  width: 500px;
}
.label {
    font-size:21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
  float: left;
}
#login {
    font-size:24px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    width:30%;
}
#logout {
    font-size:19px;
}
input.credin{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:auto;
}
input.credin.right{
  float: right;
}
```

Still, this is quick fix and you might check if some other solution is applicable.

Comment: I tried something similar. However this happened. Normally, the labels align vertically to the box, but now they just collapse. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Is it possible to check all classes that are applied to those elements? there might be something in whole css that applies rules you do not need for this part of html.

Comment: Could you elaborate further? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: There should be something collapsing your elements. If you inspect elements in e.g. Chrome dev tools, you should be able to see which css attribute is making issue. Also, example I gave you is for pure html/css. Are you using some framework, like bootstrap or similar?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<body>
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have two solution you can check

### 1 st- (directly put in your css)**

```
form {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  input {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
  }
```

---

### **2nd- (Directly put in your css)**

```
form {
  direction: rtl;
}
input {
  display: block;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple and reliable solution is to use a table.

```
<form i  d="cred">
<table>
<tr>
  <td><h3 class="credin">Username:</h3></td>
  <td><input class="credin" type="text" name="username" value=""> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><h3 class="credin">Password:</h3></td>
  <td><input class="credin" type="password" name="password" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan=2><a><p id="logout">(Sign up)</p></a><td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan=2><input id="login" type="submit" value="Log in"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

EnterSB's solution is also good, but it is difficult to scale :)